# Media player using YouTube?

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I am developing a sample application using `MediaPlayer`.By using the raw resources folder,the video can be played.But I want to play through `URL`.How can I achieve this?

#### My code is:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        // Set video link (mp4 format )
        Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1Wgp3mLa_E");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
```

Comment: Q-GLuydiMe4 id will not open through this way ? is this happen with you or not. Plaese let me knoe ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the correct streaming(rtsp) url rather than the link to the player page you are using. You can get this programmatically using the [google data api](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)

Once you have done that you would simply replace

> **"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1Wgp3mLa_E"
>   with "rtsp://v8.cache1.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnxa4t5p6BVTxMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"**

in your existing code and it should work.

**Note:**   The quality of video, when streaming to your own videoview, can be very poor compared to  how it looks when played on the youtube site or player app.

Comment: can u expand me the answer, what i should do with  google data api, i was bit confused..

Comment: Q-GLuydiMe4 id will not open through this way ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to rtsp links from gdata api :`gdata api with this: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?&max-results=20&v=2&format=1&q="+ URLEncoder.encode(activity.criteria)`

```
Element rsp = (Element)entry.getElementsByTagName("media:content").item(1);

                              String anotherurl=rsp.getAttribute("url");
```

In gdata api only we are getting this type of links : `rtsp://v3.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlOCTh0GvUeYRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp`

These are playing in VideoView.

My answer link :[RTSP Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520313/how-to-get-rtsp-links-android)

Comment: Q-GLuydiMe4 id will not open through this way ? have you aware why is it not playing ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get better quality videos, I checked what these guys did. It helped me very very much!

I'm posting the link so you can checkout their project and use [their code](http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/source/checkout).