# Unable to play RTSP file using VideoView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, streaming, android-videoview, rtsp

Following is my code I am using to play live streaming video of an RTSP response I am receiving from server.

```
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.tvvideoView);
     MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
     mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
     Uri video = Uri.parse("rtsp://122.166.229.151:1950/1346a0cf0ef7c2");
     videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
     videoView.setVideoURI(video);
     videoView.start();
```

Each time I run the code it says start() and gives me error(1,-1) MediaPlayer could not connect to client side trying server side(In log cat)...Each time the rtsp values keeps changing. I want to know does rtsp need to  have an extension like .3gp or something or is somethign wrong in my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186950/video-streaming-using-rtsp-android use this link....

Comment: Nikhil is it mandatory to use any of these servers?

Comment: "rtsp://v8.cache1.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnxa4t5p6BVTxMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"  use this and check once..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520313/how-to-get-rtsp-links-android

Comment: I could play the link you sent it is working fine. But my rtsp link isnt working :(

Comment: P.S : It does not have a .3gp extension