# How to play video in video view from youtube link in android?

Tags: android

I have tried the following code to run a YouTube video in video view.But its says this video cant be played...

```
video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        String path = "rtsp://v5.cache4.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQmiWeecHAQBrBMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYMWyte6X6MbcUAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp";

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.start();
```

Any solution please...

Comment: Why would you not want the YouTube app to deal with this via intents? The user will probably be familiar with interface and it is designed to deal with playing videos from YouTube.  When the video is done with the user will be returned to the place they came from in your app.

Comment: I have posted an answer that shows how to do what I suggest with a link to a free app that my company made for a local music artist. The app implements what I suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to the question comments this is how to use an intent that can result in YouTube app playing a YouTube video.

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", "url_to_video");                   
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

Obviously the YouTube app has to be installed and if there are multiple apps that can handle playback the user may be prompted to choose one, if they haven't selected a default app already.

If you want to see this in action you can see it in one of our free apps under the video section. We pop a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) to ask if the user wants to view the video in case they are on a limited bandwidth connection (e.g. 3G).

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wisemandesigns.android.robgreen&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the You tube url..., Substring the Video_ID from the Url.See the example below i have given.

You can use http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/VIDEO_ID api to get the rtsp link from the actual you tube url.Data is in XML format

once you get the rtsp link you can play video in VideoView here is the example

**For example**: If this link is the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMM0R19IisI

Then `sMM0R19IisI` is the Video_ID.So you can pass this video id to above api to get the rtsp link

To get Data in `JSON format` use this http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/"+videoid+"?alt=json

Refer these two links:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716146/rtsp-youtube-link)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520313/how-to-get-rtsp-links-android)

Once you get the rtsp link you can play it in VideoView