# How to play Youtube Video in android Mediaplayer

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview

I need to play a Youtube video in my android project.

Where i am using MediaPlayer not YoutubePlayer Api.
How can i get RTSP link from a video id or this type o f link..?

```
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("https://r2---sn-gvcp5mp5u5-jb2e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&ipbits=0&ei=fcp0WYamOYbcogOjyLa4Dw&pl=24&ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&mime=video%2Fmp4&expire=1500847838&initcwndbps=173750&mn=sn-gvcp5mp5u5-jb2e&itag=22&signature=C127F7D775420D4B6B212D179A8646B37050E11E.522C99F874D1F96CD0AC0F32B3237D748F5412FB&mm=31&mt=1500825996&id=o-AGZK-vdS6Nn30ULgrBRUI6BxRirCwJh_qdrglkQzAioR&dur=46.393&mv=m&source=youtube&ms=au&lmt=1472804597021430&ip=202.134.9.129&key=yt6");
```

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6522563/7461132).

Answer (score -2):

Media Player is using for playing sound, not video.
for playing video you can try to work with SurfaceView or VideoView

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

or

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: Are you sure that only sound can be played? "MediaPlayer class can be used to control playback of audio/video files and streams. An example on how to use the methods in this class can be found in VideoView." https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: yes, I'm sure.
SurfaceView is handling the video and Media Player handle the sound and they work together.

Comment: As far as I understood. MediaPlayer handles video playback and renders to SurfaceView.

Comment: Correct.
and here a good tutorial:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingMediaPlayertoplayVideoandAudio.htm

Comment: Downvoted for not doing basic research. MediaPlayer has been able to play video since the time it was created: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer